# Create visible polygon on google map on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to make accent on some area on the map.
So i wonder if there way to create coloured polygon but in next way:
my area - is normal(not coloured) map
other google map - coloured polygone

```
------------------------
|                      |
|     __________       |
|     |  my     |      | 
|     |area here|      |
|     | ordinary|      |
|     |____map_ |      |
|                      |
|   other google map   |
|    (coloured)        |
------------------------
```

any ideas or suggestions how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This link leads to Google Maps Documentations for Android [Create Polygon On Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes)